# ListComp inside generator code too complex

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, concept

This is a piece of very cryptic code that I've read and cannot follow.  I will post here and seek experts help.  It's about to decide how many minimum meeting rooms will need if given some meeting schedule.

For example, if the meetings schedule is - [[1,10], [5,12],[10,15]]
Then it will need minimum 2 rooms.

The code is following:

```
def mini_room(intervals):

    room, current = 0, 0
    for i, v in sorted(x for i, j in intervals for x in [[i,1], [j,-1]]):
        current += v
        room = max(room, current)

print(mini_room(meetings)) #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is simple. You need a counter, that increments whenever an event starts and decrements whenever an event ends. The maximum value of that counter will give you the required number of rooms.

The "confusing" statement `for i, v in sorted(x for i, j in intervals for x in [[i,1], [j,-1]])` is essentially doing this:

1. For each interval `i,j`, it breaks it into `[i,1]` and `[j,-1]`
2. Create a list of said intervals
3. Sort them and traverse it

`1` was added to `i` (in `[i,1]`) because like I explained above, the counter needs to be incremented when an event starts. `1` marks the new event, and this value gets added to the counter. Similarly, `-1` in `[j,-1]` marks the end of the event and is subtracted from the counter.

Edit:
Here's a simplified version.

```
simple = []
for i in intervals:
    simple.append([i[0],1])
    simple.append([i[1],-1])
simple.sort()
counter = 0
ans = 0
for i in simple:
    counter += i[1]
    ans = max(ans, counter)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation...will take time to digest... Much appreciated. Is it possible that you `translate` to simple loop- syntax to demo it?

Comment: @annie2020 added that as well